# Monax Ubuntu 16.04 VM Set up issue

Tags: docker, eris-industries, monax

Here is what I did.

1. Created a Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Windows using Hyper-V
   ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso
2. Did apply the Virtual switch for internet access for the Ubuntu VM
3. Ubuntu got installed with no issues
4. Did installed apt-get, ssh etc dependencies
5. Using putty was able to connect from windows host
6. After connecting did install Docker CE, Docker Machine, Virtualbox

**Docker version**

```
 Client:  
    Version: 17.09.0-ce  
    API version: 1.32  
    Go version: go1.8.3  
    Git commit: afdb6d4  
    Built: Tue Sep 26 22:42:18 2017  
    OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

**Server**

```
Version: 17.09.0-ce  
API version: 1.32 (minimum version 1.12)  
Go version: go1.8.3  
Git commit: f4ffd25  
Built: Tue Oct 17 19:05:23 2017  
OS/Arch: linux/amd64  
Experimental: false
```

**docker-machine version**

```
 docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
```

7. Created the Monax virtual box and installed Monax
8. Created a chain with this command
   monax chains start firstchain
9. The chain seems to get started perfectly
   monax ls

   SERVICE ON VERSION
   keys  0.17.0
   CHAIN ON VERSION
   firstchain  0.17.0
10. On invoking below command faced error as listed below

    monax pkgs do --chain firstchain --address $addr

**Error:**
Error connecting to node (`tcp://172.17.0.3:46657`) to get chain id: Post `http://172.17.0.3:46657:` dial `tcp 172.17.0.3:46657:` getsockopt: no route to host

Can you please highlight what is wrong.

Comment: Are you running `monax` from the virtual machine or from your host?

Comment: Host machine is Win 10. On it created Ubuntu 16.04 VM. Running monax on the Ubuntu VM. Just to add on the $addr have checked is also having the address value applied.

Comment: After recreating the VM with all the listed steps finally got the contract deployed. Not sure what exactly was the issue but seems not occurring anymore.

Comment: Good to hear that everything is working!

Comment: @CrissiMariamRobert you should create a question with all teh details of the issue faced and the steps folowed